# Overrwriting a value in memory with one in a register

Tags: assembly, memory, x86-64, memory-address, att

I have declared the following:

```
.text 
MSG:
.quad 0x0000000000000001
.quad 0x0000000000000001
.quad 0x0000000000000001
.quad 0x0000000000000001
```

And in the main subroutine I would like to change the value of the first quadword from MSG and I try to do something like this :

```
Movq %rbx, MSG(%r10, %r11, 8)
```

Where RBX contains the new value, R10 and R11 both have the value 0.
Why does this not work ? It gives me a segfault.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: `.text` sections are read-only. Also `MSG` address is 64-bit but displacements are 32-bit. Don't you get any warning about a truncated relocation?

Comment: @MargaretBloom In position-dependent code in the standard ELF medium model, the binary is loaded into the low 2 GB of the address space and you can indeed use 32 bit absolute addressing.

Comment: @fuz Yes thank you, I remembered it was possible. I thought `--pie` was the default for `ld` but I just checked and it's not.

Comment: @MargaretBloom It depends on the specific system you are programming for.  Making PIE the default has become more and more popular.

Comment: @MargaretBloom thank you! What you have said helped me a lot and you are totally right !

Comment: @MargaretBloom: `ld`'s defaults haven't ever changed, only `gcc`'s defaults, which makes sense because using the `gcc` front-end means "compile and link the normal way on this system", so that's the place to introduce a new default.  (There's even a GCC config option for what `-f` and linker options should be on by default.)  But if you manually use `ld` with only a `.o` as an arg, you're always going to get a statically linked non-PIE.